# Update Column Using ROW_Number() function. But it is failing. Could Any one suggest a solution?

Tags: sql-server-2008, row-number, administrator

I know guys, this might be a silly question, but I have not found any solution till now, so I am asking this question with all the inputs and outputs that I have done. Could anyone provide me the solution.

What I want to do is: the `parcelno` can have one or more `invoicenumbers`, I want to find how many invoice numbers does an parcel has and give it a rank. The ranking part is important because my further work is depending on this column.

I have one table named TableA. It has three columns `Invoicenumber` which is the unique id, `ParcelNo` which can be duplicate and `Ranking` which I want to update.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    Invoicenumber varchar(5), 
    ParcelNo varchar(5), 
    Ranking bit,
    IDate Datetime
)

INSERT INTO TableA (Invoicenumber, ParcelNo)
VALUES ('INV01', 'P0001'), ('INV02', 'P0001'),
       ('INV03', 'P0002'), ('INV04', 'P0002'),
       ('INV05', 'P0003'), ('INV06', 'P0003')
```

When I run the following query the output is as desired.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PARCELNO ORDER BY INVOICENUMBER) AS RWNO
    FROM 
        TableA
)
SELECT 
    T.*, C.RWNO 
FROM CTE C
JOIN TableA T ON T.Invoicenumber = C.Invoicenumber
```

The output is below:

[image]

So, I tried to update the `Ranking` column in Table A.

I run this query to do so:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PARCELNO ORDER BY INVOICENUMBER) AS RWNO
    FROM 
        TableA
)
UPDATE T 
SET Ranking = C.RWNO
FROM CTE C
JOIN TableA T ON T.Invoicenumber = C.Invoicenumber
```

But the output is wrong. The column is not updated as expected.

Below is the output of the updated column:

[image]

Why is the `Ranking` column is updated incorrectly?

I want to update the column to prepare some data. This table is sample for the explanation.

I am elaborating my issue below:-

Below in the image are two tables:-

[image]

Table A and Table B has IDate column.
I want to update the IDate column in A from B. But the dates should be unique. First date should not be repeated. These date are associated with Invoicenumbers.

Comment: One more thing to mention. I have taken the CTE output in a temporary table and tried to update, but the same output is obtained. Could anyone help me to understand what is really happening behind the scenes.

Comment: You might want to make it a little more clear what your Ranking column is supposed to convey. My answer below assumes that you wanted a count of how many invoices are in a Parcel for Ranking, but I can update my answer if Ranking is supposed to convey something else.

Comment: @bobsbeenjamin I really appreciate that you have given your precious time. But I would keep it very simple. The CTE produces the rank, I want the same rank to update. I would like to add more to my comment what you have asked. The Ranking is required because there will be dates associated to the Parcelno.

Comment: Hey the answer lies in my question itself. This wierd behaviour happened due to the data type bit. Bit takes only 0 and 1. If the value is other than this, it takes 1. @bobsbeenjamin Thank you again for your solution. It might help me in my future projects. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. So all you had to do was change the data type from bit to int?

Comment: Yes @bobsbeenjamin. I changed datatype bit to int and the miracle happened. But I got to learn the strong presence of the datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is a calculated column (called a calculated field or generated field). I'm guessing that your parcel number should point to another table that stores information about the parcels. If that's the case, then go with:

```
-- First approach
CREATE TABLE Parcels (
   id int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
   ParcelNo varchar(5),
   Description varchar(max)
   -- Ranking AS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Invoices i WHERE i.ParcelID = id)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoices (
   id int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
   InvoiceNumber varchar(5),
   ParcelID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Parcels(id)
);

ALTER TABLE Parcels ADD Ranking AS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Invoices i WHERE i.ParcelID = id);

INSERT INTO Parcels
(ParcelNo)
VALUES
('P0001'),
('P0001'),
('P0002'),
('P0003');

INSERT INTO Invoices
(InvoiceNumber, ParcelID)
VALUES
('INV01', (SELECT p.id FROM Parcels p WHERE p.ParcelNo = 'P0001')),
('INV02', (SELECT p.id FROM Parcels p WHERE p.ParcelNo = 'P0001')),
('INV03', (SELECT p.id FROM Parcels p WHERE p.ParcelNo = 'P0002')),
('INV04', (SELECT p.id FROM Parcels p WHERE p.ParcelNo = 'P0002')),
('INV05', (SELECT p.id FROM Parcels p WHERE p.ParcelNo = 'P0003')),
('INV06', (SELECT p.id FROM Parcels p WHERE p.ParcelNo = 'P0003'));
```

On the other hand, if you **really** want all the data in a single table, then try this:

```
-- Second approach
CREATE TABLE TableA (
   Invoicenumber varchar(5),
   ParcelNo varchar(5),
   Ranking AS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA a WHERE a.ParcelNo = ParcelNo)
)
```

Some notes:

- Both of my approaches assume that by ranking, you mean that you want a count of how many invoices are in a parcel.
- My first approach has a circular reference, because the Invoices table has a foreign key into the Parcels table, but the Parcels table tabulates information from the Invoices table. That's why I commented out the calculated field in the first table, then added the calculated field back in after creating both tables.
- Notice that I capitalized all SQL keywords (except the types such as varchar). It's easier to read SQL if you either go with all caps or no caps for an entire query.
- Notice my semicolons at the end of each logical break. Semi-colons are technically optional, but a lot of folks consider using them to be good practice.
- For my first approach, I'm using a foreign key. You can read more about those [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).
- Because my first approach split the table into 2 tables, I needed to somehow know the id of the Parcels table when populating the Invoices table, even though the ids are given by the database (so I can't know them ahead of time). Those select statements accomplish that.
- My syntax should work with SQL Server, but no necessarily with any other DBMS. That's because calculated fields are not ANSI standard.

Comment: I have elaborated my issue more specifically. Can you give me any solution for that. That data that I am holding is same as described in the issue. I am trying my best to do.